# Can global configurations in Joomla be specific to section?

Tags: joomla

Is there a way to have different Global Configurations for each section of articles? I want articles in Section A to open up in new windows and articles in Section B to open up in the same window, and I don't want to set the preferences article by article.

Thank you!

Comment: That wouldn't be very global of them. :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the configurations at article level. There are no in-built ways to generalize the configuration at section or category level.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Have you ever heard of any extensions that might be able to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the two sections of articles? If you're using a module then it should be possible to duplicate it and change the links.